# How do I redirect if a user visits the login page but is already logged in?

Tags: redirect, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

With Rails 5, how do I redirect a user if they visit my login page (/login) and they are already logged in?  I tried

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    ...
  def login
    respond_to do |format|
      if logged_in?
        format.html { redirect_to :controller => "my_controller", :action => "index" }
      end
    end
  end
```

in which "logged_in?" is defined in my application_controller.rb file, but I'm getting the error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

on the line

```
respond_to do |format|
```

Seems like there's probably a really simple way to do this that I'm not realizing.  Also I'm not using devise, just using my own login mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a format in case the user isn't logged in, actually you're only redirecting if the user is, try with:

```
def login
  respond_to do |format|
    if logged_in?
      format.html { redirect_to controller: 'my_controller', action: 'index' }
    else
      format.html { ... } # redirect to another place
    end
  end
end
```

I think you could create a method to redirect only if the user isn't logged in, otherwise, leave it there, I think now I get your idea. It could be in your application controller, and be applied to each controller, like:

```
before_action :require_login

private

def require_login
  redirect_to some_path unless logged_in?
end
```

And if you want to permit some actions in some controllers to be accessed without being logged in, then you can use a skip_before_action callback, like:

```
skip_before_action :require_login, only: :index # for instance
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there an easier way to do this other than what I have set up?  This seems like I could do it via a route configuraiton rather than all this code.